# Extract the minimum of a list of arrays, plot lines along with their intersections in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list that is made up of sub arrays like:

```
[array(.....),array(.....),array(.....),....]
```

All the arrays are of the same length (basically each array represents a line).

I want to extract the minimum values element by element. So if each array has 100 elements, then I want the final list to be 100 elements in length. I also want the points where these lines intersect. Something like the this should clarify what I mean:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xshkhvqp0ay3vxc/g14.png

Comment: The part where you compute minimums is `numpy.min(l, axis=0)`. Dunno about plotting or what you mean by intersections.

Comment: How do the arrays represent lines?

Comment: @user2357112 By using something like x=array(linspace(0,2.4,100)) and y=x+2 or x*3 etc... That will be linear and can represent a line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make no claims that this is the best way to do it, having not fully wrapped my mind around Python.  I have coded up a solution to a similar problem while calculating phase diagrams.  At a given temperature, for some number of free energies functions for different phases, what is the overall minimum free energy curve, and which function is the minimum at each point.

```
G = []
while iPhase < len(f): # loop through all free energy functions
    G.append(f[iPhase](x)) # x is an array of x values 
    iPhase = iPhase+1
minG = G{0][:] # define an overall minimum free energy curve, starting with 0'th
minF = np.zeros(len(minG)) # prepare for index indicating which function f[i](x) is min
iPhase = 1
while iPhase < len(f):
    nextF = iPhase*np.ones(len(x0, dtype=np.int)
    np.less(G[iPhase],minG, nextF) # where is next free energy function less than current min
    minG = np.minimum(minG, G[iPhase]) # new overall minimum
    minF = np.ma.filled(np.ma.array(minF, mask=nextF), fill_value=iPhase) # new index as needed
    iPhase = iPhase+1
```

So, the final output is an overall minimum minG, and an index of which curve it came from in minF.  Now, if you want to refine the intersection points, one can use

```
changes = np.array(np.where(minF[:-1]!=minF[1:]))
```

to return indices of where the lines crossed, and which functions were involved. If they different functions are truly lines y=mx*b, you can do the algebra to get the exact crossing.  For more complex functions, a more complex procedure will be needed (I define a temporary function as the difference of the two under consideration, and then use scipy.optimize.newton to get the zero).

Answer (score 0):

Let say that you have the following list:

```
>>> l = [array('i', [5, 15, 1, 25]),
         array('i', [5, 15, 2, 25]), 
         array('i', [5, 15, 3, 25])]
```

You can obtain minimum values of every arrays with the following:

```
>>> [min(x) for x in l]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Sorry but I don't understand the rest of your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> data = np.random.rand(3, 4)
>>> data
array([[ 0.5488135 ,  0.71518937,  0.60276338,  0.54488318],
       [ 0.4236548 ,  0.64589411,  0.43758721,  0.891773  ],
       [ 0.96366276,  0.38344152,  0.79172504,  0.52889492]])
>>> result = data.min(axis=1)
>>> result
array([ 0.54488318,  0.4236548 ,  0.38344152])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of two lines can be found by algebra
ax+b = cx+d

implies: x = (d-b) / (a-c)

Thus in python all you have to do is associate to each array a pair (a,b), these can be found by taking any two points from the array or, if you must, by a least squares fit:-)

This will give you pairwise intersections, but this is an N^2 algorithm. Presumably you can do better by sweeping, but at this point a computational geometry text is in order